# Creating surface patches using gmsh 4.11.1

Tags: gmsh

I want to create a volume mesh around a full sphere that is in a rectangular box.

How can I create surface patches, the so-called butterfly topology,see the attached figure,on a sphere surface mesh to avoid singularities?

I need 3d boundary layer mesh with structured hexahedra around the full sphere and
then can be unstructured tetrahedra or still hexahedra.

Thank you for reading and kind regards!
[image]